# Getting microphone input stream, Android API 15, to pass to Watson for speech to text

Tags: java, android, ibm-watson

I need to pass the audio to Watson for speech to text, how-ever the methods used in the documentation [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/develop/speech-to-text) does not seem to work, as for some reason the `DataLine.Info` object does not exist.

Please note that this is in Android API 15

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to include the Watson Android SDK.